# Cannot Access Automatically Populated Environment Variables in Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Functions for a Golang project, and in one of the functions, I need to use the credentials to initialize another GCP product. There's [supposed to be](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables) a pre-populated environment variable called `FIREBASE_CONFIG` that holds the credentials that I need, but when a try to access it, nothing turns up.

```
os.Getenv("FIREBASE_CONFIG")
```

(On a side note, the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/blob/master/firebase.go) also uses this environment variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIREBASE_CONFIG is only provided for functions deployed with the Firebase CLI.  The Firebase CLI only supports functions targeting a nodejs runtime.  It doesn't support golang.

If you're deploying a function written in go, you're not actually using the Firebase tools at all - you're using the Google Cloud tools (gcloud).  The Firebase specific documentation isn't going to be accurate for your case.  So, you'll have to find another way to provide yourself with the information you need at runtime.  You can [set your own environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var) if you want, or just deploy a file to read.